# How to properly connect with worker node in docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have docker setup as 1 Manager and 1 Worker. Both node are separate machine within a same network.
Initialized docker swarm in manager node and connected another PC to swarm using the `docker swarm join-token worker` code generated by manager node.

`docker info` Manager Node

```
Containers: 16
 Running: 5
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 11
Images: 303
Server Version: 18.03.1-ce
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 572
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: active
 NodeID: v5out80i284bavbkhrny82non
 Is Manager: true
 ClusterID: 2h6jhemo4ch03zzk9dm8hkn97
 Managers: 1
 Nodes: 2
 Orchestration:
  Task History Retention Limit: 5
 Raft:
  Snapshot Interval: 10000
  Number of Old Snapshots to Retain: 0
  Heartbeat Tick: 1
  Election Tick: 3
 Dispatcher:
  Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds
 CA Configuration:
  Expiry Duration: 3 months
  Force Rotate: 0
 Autolock Managers: false
 Root Rotation In Progress: false
 Node Address: 10.0.0.1
 Manager Addresses:
  10.0.0.1:2377
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 773c489c9c1b21a6d78b5c538cd395416ec50f88
runc version: 4fc53a81fb7c994640722ac585fa9ca548971871
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.13.0-37-generic
Operating System: KDE neon Developer Edition
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 7.691GiB
Name: wannamit
ID: KR2B:Q2E6:GAPR:HY6X:PYZQ:KUMU:DXCE:7YKI:E5MM:RRHO:BBWG:GM6S
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Username: amithp
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
```

`docker info` Worker Node

```
Containers: 4
 Running: 4
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 4
Server Version: 18.03.1-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: active
 NodeID: vvusfvjpenc9ymsotj4bcs25c
 Is Manager: false
 Node Address: 192.168.86.38
 Manager Addresses:
  10.0.0.1:2377
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 773c489c9c1b21a6d78b5c538cd395416ec50f88
runc version: 4fc53a81fb7c994640722ac585fa9ca548971871
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.15.0-22-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 3.093GiB
Name: ubuntu
ID: SKCQ:JZGO:VUHX:HZN5:JD4H:4KPM:5RXK:DWG2:A7E6:WU4T:VQ5N:YHQB
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
```

A Simple is deployed with 5 replication.

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  webapp:
    image: amithp/pyapp:latest
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
    ports:
      - "28888:28888"
    networks:
      - frontend-network

  redis:
    image: redis
    command: redis-server --appendonly yes
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    networks:
      - frontend-network

networks:
  frontend-network:
    external:
      name: frontend-network
```

Deployment is a success. Mostly 2 is deployed in Manager node, 3 other and Redis is deployed over worker node. The docker image is flask app that shows total view count and origin IP from app is being served.

> Hello world!
>
> Hostname: 351d83b03555
>
> HostIP: 10.0.0.28
>
> Visits: cannot connect to Redis, counter disabled

Now if I visit localhost:2888 from manager node. It cannot connect to redis and only loops over 2 different IPs. I cross-checked those IP and they are from manager node. Also, I identified IP of containers in worker node and tried to ping from manager node's container, response cannot connect to host (no ping reply).

Am I doing something wrong or did I miss something?

Comment: Is the network `frontend-network` of type overlay?

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu yes. `docker network create --driver overlay frontend-network`

Comment: what shows `docker service ps webapp`?

Comment: Something wired happened. All 5 of replicas is being discovered by each other and request is sent over all 5 instances, also redis is working.
I had to change my both machine. After I setup all in new machines, and did exactly same as before and now it works.
Dont know what was the reason previously but it is now working. I will update this post if same problem occurs.
Any idea what could have been the problem?
FYI answer to your last Q: All 5 replicas was shown as running , with correct node names in which they were running.

Comment: if happens again you can run `docker service logs -f webapp` to see what is happening inside the service containers